# ActionBar style not applied after coming back from camera

Tags: android, camera, android-actionbar

I have an `ActionBar` in my activity with a custom font and fontstyle:

```
public void setActionBar() {

        SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Create a new goal");
        s.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(getApplicationContext(), "BebasNeue Regular.otf"), 0, s.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
        actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle(s);
        int actionBarTitleId = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("action_bar_title", "id", "android");
        if (actionBarTitleId > 0) {
            Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "actionBarTitleId: " + actionBarTitleId);
            TextView title = (TextView) findViewById(actionBarTitleId);
            if (title != null) {
                Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "title: " + title);
                title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                title.setTextSize(26);
            }
        }
        actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); 
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);  
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    }
```

I call it right after onCreate(). In the activity the user can load an image into an ImageView and when I open the camera and create an image and then click BACK or just click BACK without creating the image to go back to the activity, the style resets to the default font style, the font becomes small and black.

**This is how it looks like when I open the activity:**

[image]

**This is how it looks like after coming back from camera:**

[image]

I added the lifecycle callback methods to the activity to find out where the problem is but it turns out I receive all Log messages (both in the code above) so the title should look like exactly as it looks like when I open the activity.

Lifecycle methods:

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "onStart");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "onResume");
        setActionBar(); //tried putting this here instead in onCreate
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "onPause");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "onStop");
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i("LIFECYCLE", "onDestroy");
    }
```

This is the log starting with onStop() when the activity is no longer visible:

```
10-30 21:01:00.074: I/LIFECYCLE(29143): onStop
10-30 21:01:00.094: D/HardwareRenderer(29143): startTrimMemory(level >=TRIM_MEMORY_COMPLETE)
10-30 21:01:01.634: I/LIFECYCLE(29143): onStart //coming back from camera
10-30 21:01:01.634: I/LIFECYCLE(29143): onResume
10-30 21:01:01.654: I/LIFECYCLE(29143): actionBarTitleId: 16908901
10-30 21:01:01.654: I/LIFECYCLE(29143): title: android.widget.TextView{4201dd98 V.ED.... ......ID 0,0-289,52 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_title}
10-30 21:01:01.694: I/Adreno-EGL(29143): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.041_msm8974_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1_CL3304448_release_AU (CL3304448)
10-30 21:01:01.694: I/Adreno-EGL(29143): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.14
10-30 21:01:01.694: I/Adreno-EGL(29143): Build Date: 04/18/14 Fri
10-30 21:01:01.694: I/Adreno-EGL(29143): Local Branch: 
10-30 21:01:01.694: I/Adreno-EGL(29143): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
10-30 21:01:01.694: I/Adreno-EGL(29143): Local Patches: NONE
10-30 21:01:01.694: I/Adreno-EGL(29143): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.041 +  NOTHING
10-30 21:01:01.724: I/InputMethodManager(29143): [startInputInner] EditorInfo { packageName=com.example.blgui3, inputType=0x34001, imeOptions=0x48000005, privateImeOptions=null }, windowGainingFocus=android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@41d387f0, mServedView=android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView{41b8b620 VFED..CL .F....ID 30,15-1050,152 #7f080120 app:id/actv_name}
```

Comment: I added two screenshots to visualize the result